# javascript library for Code view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a site which i need to let users add some code.

this code can be c#, jS ,jQuery, Sql.

Im having a problem of finding a professional library for code view ( like in stackoverflow ) : 
e.g.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this (support 41 languages) http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/

Comment: nice !. do you have any idea what stackoverfLow use ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir stackoverflow use http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at this?

http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/

Answer (score 1):

I've used this: http://codemirror.net/. It's an editor with syntax coloring, but can be used also just for highlighting.